# XML parser for Python to get tags before and after matching tag

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I want to write an XML parser in Python for checking which of my test cases are failing and if failing, check for error message. I want to extract only that part of test case which is failing along with other tags. 
I tried using Beautiful-soup. Couldn't succeed properly. Below is the sample of my XML file:

```
<test>
    <test_str>Test Case #1: Check for login</test_str>
    <testcase>
        <pass_status>false</pass_status>
        <criticality>true</criticality>
        <errorMsg>Invalid credentials:
Check the login credentials </errorMsg>
        <tags>
            <string>test01</string>
        </tags>
        <parent reference="../../../.."/>
        <failedSince>0</failedSince>
    </testcase>
</test>
<test>
    <test_str>Test Case 02:Pass valid credentials
by selecting valid username</test_str>
    <testcase>
        <pass_status>true</pass_status>
        <criticality>true</criticality>
        <tags>
            <string>test01</string>
        </tags>
        <parent reference="../../../.."/>
        <failedSince>0</failedSince>
    </testcase>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to *use* an XML parser, not *write* one.

You may also want to wrap the whole XML with `<tests>...</tests>` tags to make life a bit easier:

```
string = '''<tests>
            <test>
                <test_str>Test Case #1: Check for login</test_str>
                <testcase>
                    <pass_status>false</pass_status>
                    <criticality>true</criticality>
                    <errorMsg>Invalid credentials: Check the login credentials </errorMsg>
                    <tags>
                        <string>test01</string>
                    </tags>
                    <parent reference="../../../.."/>
                    <failedSince>0</failedSince>
                </testcase>
            </test>
            <test>
                <test_str>Test Case 02:Pass valid credentials by selecting valid username</test_str>
                <testcase>
                    <pass_status>true</pass_status>
                    <criticality>true</criticality>
                    <tags>
                        <string>test01</string>
                    </tags>
                    <parent reference="../../../.."/>
                    <failedSince>0</failedSince>
                </testcase>
            </test>
</tests>'''
```

Then:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_node = ET.fromstring(string)

for test_node in xml_node.findall('test'):
    test_case_node = test_node.find('testcase')
    pass_status_node = test_case_node.find('pass_status')
    if pass_status_node.text == 'false':
        print(test_case_node.find('errorMsg').text)
```

This outputs:

```
'Invalid credentials: Check the login credentials'
```

In order to read from a file simply replace `xml_node = ET.fromstring(string)` with:

```
with open('file/path') as f:
    xml_node = ET.fromstring(f.read())
```

Comment: It works when I'm adding this as part of the string. Can you please help me out to read from a file? Just trying to edit this and its failing..

Comment: You might want to rename the `string` variable.